# Artifacts when sampling texture in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I've been trying to code a fragment shader such that I can pass it an arbitrary image and it would convert it into a [9-box](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/9SliceSprites.html) (a repeating center and static borders). A sample input image would be this one:

[image]

My code then creates a single square (2 triangles), with a 1-to-1 orthographic projection that draws images fine, and call the following fragment shader:

```
    #version 330
    
    in vec2 outTexCoord;
    out vec4 fragColor;
    
    uniform sampler2D texture_sampler;
    uniform vec4 colour;
    uniform vec2 top;
    uniform vec2 mid;
    uniform vec2 bottom;
    uniform ivec2 repeat;
    
    void main()
    {
        vec2 boxSize = top + bottom + repeat * mid;
        vec2 boxCoord = outTexCoord * boxSize;
        vec2 textCoord = boxCoord;
    
        // Fiddle with the X coordinate, for items in the middle or bottom.
        if(boxSize.x - boxCoord.x <= bottom.x)
            textCoord.x = 1.0 - (boxSize.x - boxCoord.x);
        else if(boxCoord.x > top.x) {
            float m = boxCoord.x - top.x;
            m = m / mid.x;
            textCoord.x = top.x + mid.x * (m - floor(m));
        }
    
        // Fiddle with the Y coordinate, for items in the middle or bottom.
        if(boxSize.y - boxCoord.y <= bottom.y)
            textCoord.y = 1.0 - (boxSize.y - boxCoord.y);
        else if(boxCoord.y > top.y) {
            float m = boxCoord.y - top.y;
            m = m / mid.y;
            textCoord.y = top.y + mid.y * (m - floor(m));
        }
        fragColor = colour * texture(texture_sampler, textCoord);
    }
```

The uniforms are filled so that the sizes of top, mid, bottom correspond to A, B and C respectively, with `top + mid + bottom` = (1,1). The shader then extrapolates the texture coordinates that map to the original texture coordinates. The new coordinates should always fall within (0,0) and (1,1). Problem is: it works but for some reason a 2-pixel horizontal distortion appears every time I "repeat":

[image]

Another example with a different image and more vertical repeats.
[image]

What bothers me enormously is that nowhere in the original is there any empty or gray pixel to to sample from. Even if they where the wrong coordinates, it should be sampling from the texture itself (I thought it could be a sampling issue, but the error does not occur either at the frontier of the triangles nor at the frontier of the texture, nor does it seem to be interpolating from nearby texture pixels). I literally don-t know where those color values are coming from! Also, no such problem seems to occur on the X axis, even if the code is equivalent :-(

Comment: It is unclear what texture filters you are using, but your repetition code will result in non-continous jumps in the implicit derivatives of the texcoords, which means the texcoord gradients will become undefined. For your use case, you should be much better off using `textureGrad` or `textureLod`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the " implicit derivatives of the texcoords". But in any case, I´ll look it up! I have not seen any mention of those methods before, I was just using "texture" to sample a texture at a coordinate. Thanks for the pointers.